# Introduction to Analysis: Local and Global Behavior

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I've been stuck on this question for sometime now. I can't seem to figure out how to continue. The question reads:

> Prove that a function which is locally constant on $[0,1)$ is actually constant on $[0,1)$. (Suggestion: one possibility would be to consider $\sup S$, where $S = \{a < 1: \text{$f(x)$ is constant on $[0,a)$}\}$.)

From what I understand, a function is locally constant if for any $a \in I$, $f(x) = k$ for $x \approx a$. Since it is constant, would this imply the supremum and the infimum equal on that interval? I would assume so. However, what do they mean by actually constant? I would assume this refers to each point, $a$, equaling the same point value, $k$. It seems clear this is true.

Anywho, I wanted to start the proof by stating:

Let $f(x) = k$ for all $a \in [0,1)$ such that $(\exists x \approx a)$.

This is pretty much stating what I know. This is where I am stuck. The idea is simple itself but I do not know where to go about and continue the proof.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for taking the time to read this and thanks to those in advance for commenting. I really appreciate it.

Comment: "Locally constant" means that for every $x$ the function is constant on some neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: It's far better to write correctly in natural language than incorrectly with quantifier symbols. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out what $\exists x\approx a$ was supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f\colon A\to B$ is locally constant if and only if for every $a \in A$, there exists a neighborhood (think "open interval") $U$ about $a$ such that $f$ is constant on $U$.

Answer (score 0):

As in the hint, set $S=\{a\in[0,1)\left|\right.f\,\text{constant on}\,[0,a)\}$. Then $S$ in nonempty and bounded, so it has a supremum, call it $c$. We will prove that $c=1$: suppose it is not. Then, $c<1$. First, $c>0$, since $f$ is locally constant around $0$. So, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f$ is constant on $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$. But, there exists $d\in S$ such that $c-\delta<d\leq c$, so $f$ is constant on $[0,d)$, therefore it has to be constant on $[0,c+\delta)$. This is a contradiction, since $c$ is the supremum of $S$.